# how to generate pdf reports in node.js with express using jsreports

Tags: java, node.js, pdf, express, jsreport

Here is my code which i get from the http://jsreport.net/learn/pdf-reports-in-nodejs

```
var http = require('http');
var jsreport = require('jsreport');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    jsreport.render("<h1>Hello world</h1>").then(function(out) {
        out.stream.pipe(res);
    }).catch(function(e) {  
       res.end(e.message);
    });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

please help me with this i didn't get any out put for this code i am using node js with express.

Comment: Enable console logging require("jsreport").renderDefaults.logger = { providerName: "console" };

Comment: I assume you installed the jsreport module using "npm install --save-dev jsreport"? Check you haven't installed the jsreports module by mistake, maybe?

Comment: No i installed jsreport thanks anyway i figured out what wrong with my code and its done thanks again everyone